# I want to know how to solve the following question from ground frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

Particle slides down a smooth inclined plane of elevation theta, fixed in an elevator going up with an acceleration a. The base of the incline has a length L. Find the time taken by the particle to reach the bottom (solve from the inertial frame)?

I know how to solve the question from the frame of reference of the particle but I want to know how to solve it from the frame of an observer standing outside the elevator.
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As on the particle mg acting downword [image]

Comment: Hi Ram, note that we do have an equation editor (MathJax) built into the site. For details, please search `notation` in [help]. This is especially useful for the vision impaired who need screen readers where images of text cannot be parsed.